# Prolog - print true or false in print_solution write method

Tags: prolog

I want to print `true` or `false` based on some predicate `predicate` passing. For example, in Greek mythology Athena is not a descendant of Poseidon. I have all of the facts and rules correct to prove it as such, but cannot simply print in the `print_solution` method whether the predicate is true or not.

I have the rule `descendant(athena, poseidon)` that will print `false` in the interpreter as a single statement. E.g. `false` is printed if I:

```
$ prolog
['greek_mythology.pl'].
descendant(athena, poseidon).
false
```

I now want to write the same in my `print_solution` method:

```
print_solution :-
write('Athena is a descendant of Poseidon: '), write(?????), nl.
```

I tried assigning a variable in the solution and printing that:

```
print_solution :-
Z :- descendant(athena, poseidon),
write('Athena is a descendant of Poseidon: '), write(Z), nl.
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR: /.../greek_mythology.pl:164:17: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
```

Out of desperation I tried checking to see if `poseidon` was in the list of `descendant(athena, X)`:

```
setof(X, descendant(athena, X), Z), // [gaia,kronos,oranos,rheia,zeus]
member(poseidon, Z).
```

but that just gives back:

```
Z = [poseidon|_G3320] .
```

which I don't understand. Apparently `member/2` only works on lists, and `Z` is apparently not a list:

```
is_list(Z).
false.
```

How can I simply print `true` or `false` in the `write` function if the predicate returns passes like it does in the interpreter console? Desired output: `Athena is a descendant of Poseidon: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if/then/else construct in Prolog also

```
 print_solution :-
 (  descendant(athena, poseidon)
 -> Z = true
 ;  Z = false
 ),
 write('Athena is a descendant of Poseidon: '), write(Z), nl.
```

seems also could be more useful if parametrized

```
 print_solution(Desc, Anc) :-
 (  descendant(Desc, Anc)
 -> Z = true
 ;  Z = false
 ),
 format('~w is a descendant of ~w: ~w~n', [Desc, Anc, Z]).

 print_solution :- print_solution(athena, poseidon).
```

Comment: I originally wrote it exactly like this. Guess what happens when your goal has multiple solutions?

Comment: @Boris: I know you know... but OP needs basic syntax helpers, maybe

Comment: OP needs to just learn to appreciate the top level, for now :) It took me a while, too, which is why I tried to explain it in my answer. But really, esp. if you parametrize it, you are cutting away solutions (writing it here for posterity).

Comment: Okay, I see how this is working now. I attempted a similar solution after Googling Prolog if/else statements, but we couldn't get the syntax correct. I think this is a good solution as it directly solves the single problem of proving whether or not a person is a descendant of another person, rather than specifying a `goal_success` rule that could apply to any goal (though I do like the idea as a more general 'utility rule' in the event that we need `true`/`false` answers to goals rather than a list of solutions. Thank you both Capelli and @Boris !

Comment: @ChrisCirefice This is still a problematic solution. Try to apply the if-then-else to a predicate that has more than one single solution: you remove all other solutions! Compare this: `?- between(1,3,X).` to this: `?- ( between(1,3,X) -> S = true ; S = false ).` Short story, they are _not_ the same!

Comment: @Boris I understand that - Prolog is designed to provide solutions that match predicates, which is great! But I have a specific use case where I need to simply know if the predicate that I give, e.g. `descendant(athena, poseidon)` *has a solution or not*, and I want the "return value" to be `true` or `false`, has a solution or doesn't. It seems like it should be a basic operation, but maybe I'm just misunderstanding and Prolog simply isn't designed to do that... as for your code, the first finds all X where X is between 1 and 3, and the second says whether or not X is between 1 and 3, correct?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice The first one _enumerates_ (if you will) all values between 1 and 3: X = 1, X = 2, X = 3. The second one only gives you X = 1, and claims it is done. Especially since your `descendant/2` can be used with variables: `descendant(X, poseidon)`, it is a bad idea to use an if-then-else with it. You can use if-then-else safely with predicates that only succeed or fail once.

Comment: Well now I see that I have an extreme lack of fundamentals in Prolog :) frankly we've only been learning the language for a total of 6 hours in class. We never really discussed anything beyond facts, rules and some functions (`findall`, `bagof` and `setof`). That coupled with the lack of *availability* of information and usage of Prolog as compared to other languages, finding information, short of buying a textbook (that I can't afford :P), is near impossible! But I thank you for all your help with this question and my other; I also included your answer in my assignment as an alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* (not absolutely sure) that what you want is *reification* of the success or failure of a query to a truth value. A naive way to do it would be:

```
goal_success(Goal, true) :-
    Goal.
goal_success(Goal, false) :-
    \+ Goal.
```

(This has problems but read on)

Then, you can use it like this:

```
?- goal_success(descendant(athena, poseidon), S),
   /* write whatever */, write(S).
```

**However**, what you are trying to do is basically write your own meta-interpreter, and I am not sure it is really that useful. After all, what you show in your question is exactly how you would expect to interact with the Prolog *top level* (the Prolog interactive prompt). As a programmer (a human) what you want from Prolog is *answers* to your *questions*. What you give Prolog, however, is *queries*, and you get *solutions* to these queries. Your question is:

> Is Athena a descendant of Poseidon?

You evaluate the query:

```
?- descendant(athena, poseidon).
false.
```

There is no solution to this query (let's not go into the whole "closed world assumption" discussion now, it is enough to say that not being able to find a proof means that the opposite is true...)

So we interpret this as:

> Athena is not a descendant of Poseidon.

Usually, this should be enough. This is why it seems that you want to extend the Prolog top level, and write your own interpreter on top of it, which is of course fine, but more involved. Once you go down that road, you would like to interact with this interpreter like this maybe?

```
??- Is Athena a descendant to Poseidon?
?>> No, she is not!
```

Anyway, if you search the internet for "Prolog meta interpreter" you will get enough to get you started. "The Art of Prolog" by Sterling & Shapiro has a whole chapter on that, too.